How to make \orcidlinkc work in \newabbreviation?
I want to put a long orcidlink# in a \newabbreviation.
While this works:
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{orcidlink}
\usepackage[
automake,
acronyms, abbreviations, shortcuts=ac, nonumberlist, nogroupskip, section=section]{glossaries-extra}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newglossary*{USER}{USER}
\newacronym{ACRONYM}{ACRONYM}{ACRONYM}
\newabbreviation[type=USER, description={\gls*{ACRONYM}, \orcidlink{0000-0000-0000-0000}}]{user}{user}{user}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\gls{user}

\printabbreviations[type=USER]

\end{document}

the version with long versions c and f do not:
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{orcidlink}
\usepackage[
automake,
acronyms, abbreviations, shortcuts=ac, nonumberlist, nogroupskip, section=section]{glossaries-extra}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newglossary*{USER}{USER}
\newacronym{ACRONYM}{ACRONYM}{ACRONYM}
\newabbreviation[type=USER, description={\gls*{ACRONYM}, \orcidlinkc{0000-0000-0000-0000}}]{user}{user}{user}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\gls{user}

\printabbreviations[type=USER]

\end{document}

and it casts error: 5: Undefined control sequence. \setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat{1}}}.
How can long orcidlinks be used inside glossary entries?

They are not: the 1st one has orcidlink, the 2nd one orcidlinkc (final "c"). The second one does not compile.

I get no error in either case.

The error show up when use overleaf.

I get no error with an updated TeX Live 2024 and orcidlink version 1.1.0 (2024/06/26). Note that this version is the one allowing to use \orcidlinkc and \orcidlinkf that were not present in previous releases.
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{orcidlink}
\usepackage[
  automake,
  acronyms,
  abbreviations,
  shortcuts=ac,
  nonumberlist,
  nogroupskip,
  section=section,
]{glossaries-extra}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newglossary*{USER}{USER}
\newacronym{ACRONYM}{ACRONYM}{ACRONYM}
\newabbreviation[
  type=USER,
  description={\gls*{ACRONYM}, \orcidlink{0000-0000-0000-0000}}
]{a}{a}{a}
\newabbreviation[
  type=USER,
  description={\gls*{ACRONYM}, \orcidlinkc{0000-0000-0000-0000}}
]{b}{b}{b}
\newabbreviation[
  type=USER,
  description={\gls*{ACRONYM}, \orcidlinkf{0000-0000-0000-0000}}
]{c}{c}{c}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\gls{a}

\gls{b}

\gls{c}

\printabbreviations[type=USER]

\end{document}



Thanks. So the reason is the package version shipped with MacTeX 13 March 2024.
